# How to create markers to group AngularJS ng-repeat output by date (month)?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

For a project I'm doing I'm outputting an array of data using `ng-repeat` from AngularJS and am trying to group the output by Month. There's no need to orderBy, since the data I get is already sorted, I just need to group it by Month.

The data I get from the API looks similar like this:

```
{"userinfo": [{
    "date": "1305838800000",
    "name": "john",
    "lastname": "dough",
    "city": "",
    "province": "noord-holland",
    "device": "macbook",
    "phone": "iphone",
    "provider": "t-mobile"
}, {
    "date": "1305838800000",
    "name": "john",
    "lastname": "",
    "city": "amsterdam",
    "province": "noord-holland",
    "device": "macbook",
    "phone": "iphone",
    "provider": "vodafone"
},{
    "date": "1305838800000",
    "name": "john",
    "lastname": "",
    "city": "amsterdam",
    "province": "noord-holland",
    "device": "macbook",
    "phone": "iphone",
    "provider": "t-mobile"
}, {
    "date": "1305838800000",
    "name": "john",
    "lastname": "",
    "city": "amsterdam",
    "province": "noord-holland",
    "device": "macbook",
    "phone": "iphone",
    "provider": "vodafone"
}]}
```

In here the field `field` would be the epoch date of the date I want to group by.

Any help on this grouping matter would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this functionality will not land in AngularJS core:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1649

You can either go with re-grouping an array into a map object on scope (Underscore.JS's groupBy is a nice example) or creating a new groupBy filter/use existing ones like:

https://github.com/samstokes/ng-group/

One plus for regrouping on scope - it will only happen once, while filters are re-evaluated on each digest.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. Now my grouping looks something like this:
`<div ng-repeat="members in memberList | groupBy:'date':'membersByDate'"><div>{{ date | date:'MMMM' }}</div><div ng-repeat="member in members.items">{{ name }} {{ last name }}</div></div>`

Answer (score 0):

There's no support for this kind of grouping in built-in angular directives. You'll need to create a copy of your model that you get from the server (a new collection), "manually" group the objects in the according months (by date) and then loop over that copy (in the view by using ng-repeat) instead of looping over the original model.